# Elementwise division of sparse matrices, ignoring 0/0

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, division

I have two sparse matrices E and D, which have non-zero entries at the same places. Now I want to have `E/D` as a sparse matrix, defined only where D is non-zero.

For example take the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy

E_full = np.matrix([[1.4536000e-02, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.7914321e+00, 2.6854320e-01, 4.1742600e-01, 0.0000000e+00],
                    [9.8659000e-03, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 1.9106752e+00, 5.7283640e-01, 1.4840370e-01, 0.0000000e+00],
                    [1.3920000e-04, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 9.4346500e-02, 2.8285900e-02, 4.3967800e-02, 0.0000000e+00],
                    [0.0000000e+00, 4.5182676e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 7.3000000e-06, 1.5100000e-05, 4.0746900e-02],
                    [0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 3.4002088e+00, 4.6826200e-02, 0.0000000e+00, 2.4246900e-02, 3.4529236e+00]])
D_full = np.matrix([[0.36666667, 0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.2       , 0.1       , 0.        ],
                    [0.23333333, 0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.4       , 0.03333333, 0.        ],
                    [0.06666667, 0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.4       , 0.2       , 0.        ],
                    [0.        , 0.63636364, 0.        , 0.        , 0.04545455, 0.03030303, 0.28787879],
                    [0.        , 0.        , 0.33333333, 0.33333333, 0.        , 0.22222222, 0.11111111]])
E = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(E_full)
D = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(D_full)
```

Then division `E/D` yields a full matrix.

```
matrix([[3.96436360e-02,            nan,            nan, 5.37429635e+00, 1.34271600e+00, 4.17426000e+00,            nan],
        [4.22824292e-02,            nan,            nan, 5.73202566e+00, 1.43209100e+00, 4.45211145e+00,            nan],
        [2.08799990e-03,            nan,            nan, 2.83039503e-01, 7.07147500e-02, 2.19839000e-01,            nan],
        [           nan, 7.10013476e+00,            nan,            nan, 1.60599984e-04, 4.98300005e-04, 1.41541862e-01],
        [           nan,            nan, 1.02006265e+01, 1.40478601e-01,            nan, 1.09111051e-01, 3.10763127e+01]])
```

I also tried a different package.

```
import sparse
sparse.COO(E) / sparse.COO(D)
```

This got me an error.

```
ValueError: Performing this operation would produce a dense result: <ufunc 'true_divide'>
```

So it tries to create a dense matrix as well.

I understand this is due to the fact that `0/0 = nan`. But I am not interested in these values anyway. So how can I avoid computing them?

Comment: `csr` matrices are used for math, not `coo` or `dok`.  Because of all the 0's, sparse element wise divide is not actually defined.  The result will be non-sparse with these `nan` or `inf` values.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: (Inspired by sacul) Create an empty dok_matrix and modify only `D`'s nonzero part with `nonzero`. (This should work for sparse matrices other than `dok_matrix` as well.)

```
F = scipy.sparse.dok_matrix(E.shape)
F[D.nonzero()] = E[D.nonzero()] / D[D.nonzero()]
```

---

You can try the [`update`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.update.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.update) + [`nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.nonzero) method for `dok_matrix`.

```
nonzero_idx = [tuple(l) for l in np.transpose(D.nonzero())]
D.update({k: E[k]/D[k] for k in nonzero_idx})
```

First, we use `nonzero` to nail down the indices in the matrix `D` that is not 0. Then, we put the indices in the `update` method where we supply a dictionary

```
{k: E[k]/D[k] for k in nonzero_idx}
```

such that the values in `D` will be updated according to this dictionary.

**Explanation:**

What `D.update({k: E[k]/D[k] for k in nonzero_idx})` does is

```
for k in {k: E[k]/D[k] for k in nonzero_idx}.keys():
    D[k] = E[k]/D[k]
```

Note that this changes `D` in place. If you want to create a new sparse matrix rather than modifying `D` in place, copy `D` to another matrix, say `ret`.

```
nz = [tuple(l) for l in np.transpose(D.nonzero())]
ret = D.copy()
ret.update({k: E[k]/D[k] for k in nz})
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple implementation using `multiply`:

```
def sparse_divide_nonzero(a, b):
    inv_b = b.copy()
    inv_b.data = 1 / inv_b.data
    return a.multiply(inv_b)
```

To be used as:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse

N, M = 4, 4
M1 = sp.sparse.random(N, M, 0.5, 'csr')
M2 = sp.sparse.random(N, M, 0.5, 'csr')

M3 = sparse_divide_nonzero(M1, M2)

print(M1, '\n')
#   (0, 1)  0.9360024198546736
#   (1, 1)  0.625073080022902
#   (1, 2)  0.4086612951451881
#   (2, 0)  0.06864456080221182
#   (2, 1)  0.9871542989102963
#   (2, 3)  0.4371900022237898
#   (3, 0)  0.12121502419640318
#   (3, 3)  0.22950388104392383 

print(M2, '\n')
#   (1, 0)  0.9753308317090571
#   (1, 2)  0.29870724277296024
#   (1, 3)  0.21116220574550637
#   (2, 1)  0.5039729514070662
#   (2, 2)  0.4463809800134303
#   (3, 0)  0.36751994181969416
#   (3, 1)  0.6189763803260612
#   (3, 2)  0.3870101687623324 

print(M3, '\n')
#   (1, 2)  1.368099719817645
#   (2, 1)  1.9587446035629748
#   (3, 0)  0.3298189034212229
```

Comment: `inv_b.data = 1 / inv_b.data` is the line I was looking for ; it's interesting that you can do a point-wise inversion this way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is problem that you have `nan` values, it's expected result.

If you wanna replace `nan` with `0` you can use `np.nan_to_num` (doc: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html)

Comment: I will not access these nan-values anyway, so changing them does not solve the problem that they are computed and stored, thus wasting time and space.

Comment: @Hennich, I don't think you waste time in doing the actual arithmetic (`0/0` is not actually calculated with sparse matrix arithmetic in `scipy`, at least in some sparse formats), but you do waste a lot of space for big matrices, and you waste *some* time in actually *producing* the dense from the result of the operation.