# Fast insertion of sparse matrix into an other one

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I'd like to know if there is a more efficient way in python to achieve my goal. I need to insert a sparse matrix (M2) into an other one (M1). Both sparse matrix are csr

If both matrix have a value at the same index M2 overwrite M1.

For the moment I use this code:

```py
N, M = 1000, 1000
M1 = sp.random(N,M,0.1,'csr')
M2 = sp.random(N,M,0.1,'csr')

def sparse_insert(M1, M2):
    """
    return the insertion of sparse matrix M2 into sparse matrix M1
    """
    out = M1.tolil()
    idxnnz, idynnz = M2.nonzero()
    for i, j in zip(idxnnz, idynnz):
        out[i, j] = M2[i, j]
    return out.tocsr()

M3 = sparse_insert(M1, M2)
```

I'm open even to suggestions using numba or cython.
Thanks

Comment: How about merging the `coo` attributes of the two matrices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vectorized approach exploiting the properties of addition and multiplication, and using `divide_nonzero()` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58446948/5218354):

```
def divide_nonzero(a, b):
    inv_b = b.copy()
    inv_b.data = 1 / inv_b.data
    return a.multiply(inv_b)


def sparse_insert_vect(a, b):
    return a + b - divide_nonzero(a.multiply(b), b)
```

To check that this gives identical results as yours:

```
import scipy as sp
import scipy.sparse

N, M = 1000, 1000
M1 = sp.sparse.random(N, M, 0.1, 'csr')
M2 = sp.sparse.random(N, M, 0.1, 'csr')


print(sp.all(sp.isclose(sparse_insert(M1, M2).data, sparse_insert_vect(M1, M2).data)))
# True
```

But with much better timings:

```
%timeit sparse_insert(M1, M2)
# 1 loop, best of 3: 1.84 s per loop
%timeit sparse_insert_vect(M1, M2)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 5.88 ms per loop
```